# Vue - When to use functional component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-cli

I don't know when it's better to use a functional components and why it's important? I just know that it may affect performance but how? and also except the changes in props calling, I don't know what else may change.

Normal component `ChildComponent.vue`:

```
<template>
    <div>{ name }</div>
</template>
```

Functional component `ChildComponent.vue`:

```
<template functional>
    <div>{ props.name }</div>
</template>
```